# Click on row to edit/delete?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am using CI to generate a table

```
$query = $this->expenses_model->expenses_table();

//gary's code went here

$this->load->library('table');
$tmpl = array ('table_open'  => '<table class="table">');
$this->table->set_template($tmpl);

// gary added 'Edit' at end of array

$this->table->set_heading('Date', 'Plant', 'Expense', 'Category', 'Notes');

//when using gary's code, changed $query below to $data

$table['tab'] = $this->table->generate($query);     
$this->load->view('vw/exp/expenses_vw', $table, TRUE);
```

which runs through jQuery DataTables on client side using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('.table').dataTable( {
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sScrollX": "",
                "bSortClasses": false,
                "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']],
                "bAutoWidth": true,
                "bInfo": true,
                "sScrollY": "100%", 
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bRetrieve": true
                } );    
    } );
```

**Question #1**
Each record on the database has a unique autoincrement ID `record_id` that would need to be passed to each row. But this `record_id` column cannot show in the front end (ie needs to be hidden). How do we do this via CI?

**Question #2**
What kind of JS should I use to allow the user to click on the row and get a popup with a form for edit/delete?.

Thanks for helping!

PS - here is the model to generate table data

```
function expenses_table()
{
    $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

    $this->db->select('record_id, date_format(date, \'%c/%d/%Y\'), plant_name, concat(\'$ \', format(value_1, 2)), value_2, value_3', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('data');
    $this->db->join('plants', 'plants.plant_id = data.plant_id_fk');
    $this->db->where('category_1', 'expenses');
    $this->db->where('data.id_fk', $id);
    $this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Add a new column `Edit`**

```
$this->table->set_heading('Date', 'Plant', 'Expense', 'Category', 'Notes', 'Edit');
```

**2. Build the edit link based on the record_id for each record and hide record_id**

```
 $data = array();

 while ($row = $query->result_array())
 {
   $anchor = '<a href="#" class="edit_record" record_id="' . $row['record_id'] . '">Edit</a>';

   // Hide the record_id in the table output
   unset($row['record_id']);

   // Let's add the link so we can edit this entry
   $row[] = $anchor;

   // Lets push the new row so it can be output
   $data[] = $row;

 }

 $table['tab'] = $this->table->generate($data);
```

**3. Use jQuery to interact with the rows:**

```
 $('a.edit_record').click(function() {
 var record_id = this.attr('record_id');

 // Lets generate the magical lightbox here...   

 });
```

There are many lightbox plugins available for jQuery, that can accept HTML. All you'll need to do is create an ajax controller to that handles the request, uses the model to edit/delete and return the result in JSON.

[jquery lightbox html (Google)](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&xhr=t&q=jquery+lightbox+html&cp=17&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=jquery+lightbox+h&pbx=1&fp=5e53b78a8b030a8c)

Comment: @gary green - thanks for the response -- please see my update above, I added the model I use to generate table data - I am not using a loop or `while` - any idea how to `unset` `record_id` in my situation?

Comment: @gary green -- the other issue is that while `unset` will remove the column, it will not allow me to use `record_id` to make each row unique

Comment: What is it that you actually need? Now your talking about making each row unique?...

Comment: yes - as above `Question #1 -- Each record on the database has a unique autoincrement ID record_id that would need to be passed to each row. But this record_id column cannot show in the front end (ie needs to be hidden). How do we do this via CI?` -- I need each row to be unique so that when user clicks on it, that unique ID (aka record_id) will allow edit/delete of that specific record

Comment: thanks for the update Gary! still not working -- please see my OP where I indicate where your code is going -- I get a long page of errors with `Undefined index: record_id` -- I made no other changes elsewhere (model, etc)

Comment: Make some notes on: http://sync.in/qHk2Kjj41J and I'll try and help further there.